# When a periodic function is squared (or cubed, and so on...) does it always lose its periodicity?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, trigonometry, periodic-functions

For instance $$\sin^{2}\left(-\frac{\pi}{6}\right) = \sin^{2}\left(\frac{\pi}{6}\right)$$

i.e., $\sin^2 (x)$ is an even function and loses the $2\pi$-periodicity of $\sin x $.

Is this true in general?

Does $\tan^2 x$ lose the $\pi$-periodicity of $\tan x$?  The $\tan^2 x$ function still blows up wherever $\cos^2 x$ is equal to zero - I am currently studying $\tan^2 x$'s singularities to try to understand a solution to a problem I've been working on.

Comment: If $f(x)$ is periodic, then $g(x)=f(x)^2$ defines a periodic function with the same period (but not necessarily the same *minimum* period).

Comment: If $f$ is periodic with period $T$ then $g \circ f$ is also periodic with period $T$. If $g$ is one-to-one then this is the minimal period. But if, say, $f(x+\pi)=-f(x)$ then $f^2$ will be periodic with period $\pi$.

Comment: We can (almost) use your example. The function $(\sin^2 x)^2$ has rhe same minimum period as the function $\sin^2 x$.  And for cube, the function $(\sin x)^3$ has the same minimum period as $\sin x$.

Comment: I believe that if $f$ doesn't change sign (assuming $f$ is real-valued), then $f$ and $f^2$ have the same minimal period. Also, $f^2$ and $|f|$ have the same minimal period for the same reason. This illuminates the example of @Ian.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help, everyone - really appreciated :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is periodic with period $T$, i.e., $f(t + T) = f(t)$ for all $t$, then certainly $f^n$ is also periodic of period $T$ as $$f^n(t) = (f(x))^n = (f(t + T))^n = f^n(t+T)$$

However $f^n$ can also pick up other shorter periods, as your example of $f = \sin$ illustrates: $\sin$ has period $2\pi$ as does $\sin^2$; but $\sin^2$ also has period $\pi$. The minimum period of $\sin^2$ of $\pi$ is therefore less than the minimum period of $2\pi$ for $\sin$.

$\tan$ has period $\pi$, as does $\tan^2$. What $\tan^2$ does *not* have is a minimum period less the minimum period of $\tan$.

Comment: Interesting comment about tan(x), @simons.  So, $tan^{2}$ does not blow up in shorter intervals.  ... I am guessing that there is no rule to figure out the shorter periods (if any) that a composition of periodic functions can pick up, so studying the periods of a composition must be done on a case-by-case basis?

Comment: I can't think of any general rules worth remembering. So I would proceed case-by-case.

Comment: Ok got it - thanks so much @simons!

Answer (score 4):

It's still true that
$$
\sin^2(x+2\pi)=\sin^2x
$$
so certainly $\sin^2$ is periodic with period $2\pi$. It has a different *minimum* period, since, as you observe, $\sin(-x)=-\sin x$, so also
$$
\sin^2(x+\pi)=\sin^2 x
$$

Answer (score 1):

What do you think of the periodic function having $1$ for period and defined by $f(x)= 0$ for $ x \in [0,1/2)$ and by $f(x)=1$ for $ x \in [1/2,1)$?

Answer (score 1):

How about the Dirichlet's function? $$\mathbf 1_\Bbb Q: \Bbb R\ni x \mapsto \begin{cases} 1 & \mbox{for } x \in \mathbb Q, \\ 0, & \mbox{for } x \notin \mathbb Q.
\end{cases}$$
It is periodic with each rational number being its period, and is retains all those periods when raised to a natural power $$\forall_{n\in\Bbb N^+} (\mathbf 1_\Bbb Q(x))^n = \mathbf 1_\Bbb Q(x)$$

Same applies to any periodic function $\Bbb R\to \{0, 1\}$.

Answer (score -1):

Let $f$ be a periodic function of (minimum) period $T$ and let $g(x)=\left(f(x)\right)^2$.

$\textbf{Proposition:}$ *$g$ have a (minimum) period of $\frac{T}{2}$ iff $f(x+\frac{T}{2})=\pm f(x)$*

$\textbf{Proof:}$ *Left to the reader.*

Comment: Your conjecture isn't true (and neither is your proposition, unless we read the choice of sign to precede the choice of $x$ - it's a little unfair to leave the proof to the reader). Take $f$ defined as follows: For $x\in [0,2]$ we have $f(x)=\sin(\pi x)$ and for $x\in [2,4]$ we have $f(x)=-\sin(\pi x)$. We extend it to the whole real line by setting $f(x)=f(x+4)$. Obviously, $f$ has period $4$ and for all $x$ we have $f(x+2)=\pm f(x)$. $f(x)^2=\sin(\pi x)^2=\frac{1-\cos(2\pi x)}{2}$ which has period $1$.

Comment: @Meelo I forgot to add that $f$ is differentiable. And what's wrong with the proposition?

Comment: Take my $f$ and cube it - then it's differentiable. (If you want smooth, you can even build $f$ using [bump functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_function) instead of sine. I don't know about analytic). Also, the condition in your proposition may either be taken as "... iff $\forall x\in\mathbb R\exists c\in \{-1,1\}[f(x)=cf(x+\frac{T}2)]$ (which is false) or $\exists c\in \{-1,1\}\forall x\in\mathbb R[f(x)=cf(x+\frac{T}2)]$ (which is true) - but it's ambiguous as written, and looks more like the former case.

Comment: @Meelo I'm not talking about $f^3$; I said your $f$ isn't differentiable. As for the proof: If $g$ has a minimum period of $\frac{T}{2}$ then $g\left(x+\frac{T}{2}\right)=f^2\left(x+\frac{T}{2}\right)=g(x)=f^2(x)$ which gives $f\left(x+\frac{T}{2}\right)=c_xf(x)$ where $c_x\in\{-1;~1\}$. The converse is obvious.